# What verses of Tanach have penultimate stress on every word?

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk

Saying [*kaparos*](/tags/kaparot/info) this year, I noticed that *Iyov* 33:24, which is included in the rite, has all its words *mil'el*, i.e. with the penultimate rather than the ultimate syllable stressed. (Most words in Hebrew have ultimate stress; in *Tanach*, the rest have penultimate stress.) That got me wondering: What other entire verses have every word with penultimate stress?

Comment: Kind of similar: simanim points out that the pasuk ושמרתם מצותי in rishon of שור או כשב has a mafsik on every word.

Comment: בפקודיך אשיחה ואביטה ארחתיך. דרך פקודיך הבינני ואשיחה בנפלאותיך Seems likely there are a fair amount of others. Can you include some reason to think someone already put together a complete list or that it's worth investing our time to do so? If you're just curious if others exist, then the above should be a sufficient answer.